# Bash Alias Adding a Background Process

Tags: bashrc

In my .bashrc, I want to put something like this.

```
alias lst='ls &'
```

So that I can do something like this.

```
$ lst /tmp
```

which will be translated into

```
$ ls /tmp &
```

How can I do the above?

Answer (score 10):

Use a function instead.

```
lst() { ls "$@" & }
```